# need input on a NCFTP shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a shell script which uploads a local directory tree to a remote server.
This part of the code works fine. However when i add the chmod command i get the ncftp> shell.

Can someone help me out? This is the code i have:

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo "Afbeeldingen uploaden..."
ncftpput -Rvm -u "username" -p "password" domain.com /domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/gallery /Shared\ Items/Beeld/LowRes/*
ncftp -u "username" -p "password" domain.com
ncftp chmod -R 777 /domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/gallery/*
quit
echo "Klaar!"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the `chmod` command to the `ncftpput` command directly.

The option `-X` can be used to execute a command on each of the uploaded files. Here is an example with a single file that should be executable on the server:

```
ncftpput -u "username" -p "password" domain.com \
-X "chmod 0755 /remotepath/hello_world" /remotepath /localpath/hello_world
```

It is possible to use `%s` to match each of the uploaded files.

```
ncftpput -u "username" -p "password" domain.com \
-X "chmod 0755 %s" /remotepath localpath/*
```

The option `-d put.log` helped me to track my problem down. It seams that the local file path is used for %s. So localpath and remotepath should be related.

The documentation to ncftpput is available online, too: http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html.